# textView.post resets TextView marquee behavior Android

Tags: android, post, textview, reset, marquee

I am showing a some text on my loading screen. I have set TextView properties to make is scroll text but I also have another TextView that shows the current item being loading.

when I do `TextView.post(new Runnable...` it resets the marquee text e.g

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
... partial text has been passed and..
---------------------------------|---------------------------------
                             Here it posts to set loading text new status and my mruquee text again starts scrolling from start although it has to continue scroll..
```